# WebViewClient onKeyDown override errors

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok, so I get theses errors
i dont know why i get this but it seems the for the rest of the world it works for them if theres another way i have to go about doing this i will change the code but it seems as of right now my eclipse doesn't like me very much

```
The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) of type XvGForm.XvGFormClient must override or implement a supertype method
```

and

```
The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type WebViewClient
```

CODE

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {

        mWebView.canGoBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

ok so here is the full code

```
package com.xtremevisiongaming.xtremevisiongamingformapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.Window;
public class XvGForm extends Activity {

   private WebView mWebView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xv_gform);

    mWebView = (WebView)  findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.xtremevisiongaming.com/forum/forum.php");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new XvGFormClient());



  }
 private class XvGFormClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{ 
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {

        mWebView.canGoBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_xv_gform, menu);
    return true;
   }

 }
```

Comment: For one thing, you probably want to remove the semi-colon (;) after the 'if'

Comment: What kind of class is this function defined in ?

Comment: i cant tell you because im very new to android dev if you would like i can post my full code here?

Comment: at the beginning of the file you should have something like 'public class .... {', can you copy that line? If the whole source file is not too big, you can put that also (or put it on pastebin.com if it is much larger)

Comment: i posted the full code hope this helps you more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that right now the `onKeyDown` function is declared inside the `private class XvGFormClient extends WebViewClient`

You just need to move one closing brackets up by one function. I add some indentation, maybe that will help you see it:

```
private class XvGFormClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    { 
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {

        mWebView.goBack(); // go back in only the web view
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: ok now i have a different problem the button now wont return the page it just does nothing